# Lighting not updating on every frame

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

The lamps in this scene are stationary. Only the lit object is moving.

However, in this render, it seems like the lighting is being baked onto the object for several frames (perhaps 8 or 10) at a time, instead of being smoothly updated on every frame. Is that a bug?

If not, what could I be doing wrong?

Help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

https://youtu.be/0drCC_cSPOc?t=4s

Comment: It almost looks like it could be a result of too much compression on the video. Does this effect appear when rendered out to an image sequence or a less-compressed video?

Comment: I think you might be right, @gandalf3.

Comment: I have since made the video with vastly different rendering settings, different rendering engine, different materials and with rendering to PNG frames. The problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

What render engine are you using to produce this animation, and what technique did you employ to make those 'bumps' or voxels in the surface?

Is it actual modeled geometry, or is it just bump mapping? Perhaps a or normal map or use of displacement?
How did you model the underlying sphere geometry?

It looks like it *is* updating lighting in real time, what you are seeing is just an artifact of smooth shading on a low number of subdivisions.

It looks like you are using an icosphere and since this sphere seems to have an insufficient number of subdivisions what you are seeing may be the result of Blender shading a larger flat face, and light just seems to 'stick' to it instead of accompanying the curved surface our eyes are led to believe is there through smooth shading.

With the rotating motion light just seems to jumps as reaches or stops reaching these large flat faces.

Can you post a blend file we can look at, it's hard to tell for sure just looking at the video. Or perhaps a wire-frame image of your viewport.

I would recommend trying to increase the number of subdivisions on the base geometry of your sphere and see if it improves.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Blender Render was used. The exterior 'bumps' are modelled geometry (icospheres). The apparent underlying sphere is actually nothing, so there aren't any big underlying facets/faces there to create lighting artefacts. Only the tiny exterior icospheres exist. The blend file is about 17 MB. I will try to attach it, if possible.